# How to set a parameter value in mySql select statement

Tags: c#, mysql

I want set a parameter value in a Mysql query in C#.

My query is:

`SELECT @param1:=id  FROM X WHERE nation_code='8989899'`;

This is the query in SQL section in PHPMyAdmin.

In C#, I create command and add a parameter to it

`command.Parameters.Add("@param1",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.String);`

When I execute the query I receive a syntax error near

`:=id  FROM`

I changed **:=** to **=** .query execute but @param1 is NULL.

Comment: Please post your full code.  These snippets are not enough to answer your question effectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT id INTO @param1 FROM X WHERE nation_code='8989899';
   command.Parameters.Add("@param1",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.String).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

If I am understanding the query, you want to retrieve the value from @param1.

Once you have the output set, run the command, then retrieve the value from that parameter.